# API: QueueAccess (SOAP): Allowed Attributes Within "List" Element

Tags: soap, sabre

I'm trying to display details for PNRs within a certain queue and am not sure about the accepted attributes within the "List" element that would allow me to receive them.

So far, I know that the following attributes are allowed:

- IND="true"
- PrimaryPassenger="true"

What other attributes are allowed by this element?

I tried other attributes like "Remarks" or "FF" but these returned with the error:

stl:Messagecvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'Remarks' is not allowed to appear in element 'List'.</stl:Message>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from Sabre:

Only the following attributes are allowed:

```
IND="true"
PrimaryPassenger="true"
```